# Function edit needed

Tags: javascript, url, href

Currently, the following code takes a href and lines up all the parameters to be called upon later:

```
function getUrlVars() {
    var vars = {};
    var parts = window.location.href.replace(
        /[?&]+([^=&]+)=([^&]*)/gi,
        function (m, key, value) {
            vars[key] = value;
        });
    return vars;
}
```

That works with a href that has parameters set up like parameter=value in the url.  I found this function online and do not understand a lot of javascript but need to edit it so that instead of = being the dividing factor between parameter and value it is %3A instead.  So for example parameter%3Avalue due to a different format on the website I am working on.  I am not sure how the function works so I am having a hard time editing it.  Thank you for your help.

Comment: `/[?&]+([^=&]+)%3A([^&]*)/gi`?

Comment: Dictionary comes back empty if I do that.

Comment: can you provide some actual example then

Comment: Maybe changing your regex to ```[?&]+([^%3A&]+)%3A([^&]*)``` will do the trick. Also, you really need to change the title of your question :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there are multiple items you need in decoded format, you should try applying decodeURIComponent to the href string first. If it's just the %3A that you want decoded throughout, it would probably be easiest to just decode that first (so that the string does look like it uses `=` signs).

```js
function getUrlVars() {
        var vars = {};

        var partsWithEqSign = window.location.href.replace(/%3A/g, "=");

        var parts = partsWithEqSign.replace(/[?&]+([^=&]+)=([^&]*)/gi, function(m,key,value) {
            vars[key] = value;
        });
        return vars;
    }
```

Btw, the bit of code being used involves regular expressions, which are one of the most difficult concepts in JavaScript, but are really useful once you learn them.

Comment: This is a really good idea I had not thought of.  The url uses = as well it's just not what I need it for so may need to replace them with something else.  I will try this method and get back to you.

Comment: Wonderful. Glad to hear it.

Answer (score 0):

```
/[?&]+([^=&]+)%3A([^&]*)/gi
```

for something like: ?parameter%3Avalue

```
/([^=&]+)%3A([^&]*)/gi
```

for something like: parameter%3Avalue

It is using a RegEx which is matching a part of the string. And the replace method will replace the matching part with the second argument (in your example a function). Next time you can use a Regex tester like e.g. https://regex101.com

Comment: When I use that replacement in the code the dictionary comes back empty.  f=make%3AAcura&f=drivetrain%3AAll-Wheel%20Drive is the part of the url I am trying to pull values from it helps.